# Centos8: VM does not mount /boot after moving from VMware ESXi to HyperV

Tags: centos

After moving Centos8 from ESXi to Hyper-V my server can not mount /boot with error like:

```
unknown filesystem type 'ext4'
```

It does enter maintenance mode but /boot folder is empty as could not be mounted.

How can I enable ext4 on boot to mount /boot?

Comment: Exactly how did you "move" the virtual machine? Explain every step you took.

Comment: I just consolidated snapshoots then used a StarWind converter to get vhdx disk file. Then I put file into new HyperV instance. It's working for numer of Linuxes. Same day I converted Archlinux and two firewalls. The only issue I had was with drive's UUID and network cards naming. But with Centos it seems it can not load ext4 kernel module.

Comment: As for  no now solution :( The strange is that about one year old backup, using older kernel, did convert properly and is running.

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps to convert Centos 8 VMWare instance into Hyper-V one.

Remove vmware-tools.

Rebuild image with:

```
dracut --force --no-hostonly
```

Install hyper-v tools

Halt instance.

Copy & Convert your VMWare hdd image to Hyper-V format.

Start new hyper-v machine instance then enter "maintenance mode" grub2 menu item.

Rebuild image again:

```
dracut --force
```

Reboot